# The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter passport authentication

Tags: laravel, token

I'm using passport auth  with lumen for my project, and  the setup with default routes . However i tryied  to test my login route from the AuthLoginController and i have back :
`"Client error: POST http://api.restservice/v1/oauth/token resulted in a` 400 Bad Request `response:\n{\"error\":\"invalid_request\",\"error_description\":\"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid paramet (truncated...)\n"`.

postman json

```
{
    "client_secret" : "IFCeKiKNA7zdmOC1yzgWQJvxtHKHOu1WwdDq1hMH",
    "grant_type" : "password",
    "client_id" : "2",
    "email" : "fhegmann@example.com",
    "username" : "fhegmann@example.com",
    "password" : "123456"
}
```

AuthLoginController.php

```
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;

        //the fields if empty or not

        if (empty($email) or empty($password)) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' =>  'You must fill all fields']);
        }

        $client = new Client();

        try {
            return $client->post('http://api.restservice/v1/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'client_secret' => 'IFCeKiKNA7zdmOC1yzgWQJvxtHKHOu1WwdDq1hMH',
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id ' => 2,
                    'username' => $request->email,
                    'password' => $request->password
                ]
            ]);
        } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try sending as `JSON`. Change the `form_params` to `json`

Comment: I tryied all type of body `app/json, form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded`, and removing from the object body on postman the `username`  .....  nothing, the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unnecessary searches for logic solutions i find that in `form_params` block `client_id` has a space caracter before parenthesis.